# How to sort a PHP by date

Tags: php, arrays

Here is my array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 01:25:34 )
    [1] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 04:51:37 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 04:52:31 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 05:50:48 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 03:25:34 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 05:39:33 ) 
    [6] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 03:25:34 ) 
    [7] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 07:07:09 ) 
    [8] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 07:07:23 ) 
    [9] => Array ( [0] => content here [1] => 2010-02-04 08:51:18 ) 
)
```

How can I sort it by the timestamp?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/usort) with [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
function compare($e1, $e2) {
    $t1 = strtotime($e1[1]));
    $t2 = strtotime($e2[1]));

    if($t1 == t2) {
       return 0;
    }
    return ($t1 > $t2) ? 1 : -1;
}


usort($array, 'compare');
```

Comment: In this particular case, the date strings are formatted such that a basic comparison will suffice either with comparison operators (e.g. `>`) or simply `return strcmp($e1[1], $e2[1]);`

Comment: @salathe: You are probably right. I was not sure about the string comparsion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`usort()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with a `cmp_function` that compares index 1 of each of the passed arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php).

Answer (score 0):

[array_multisort()](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)  It's a nasty but powerful little function.  Basically you'll have to iterate through your array, pulling out the date stamp into a new array - maintaining key association.  Then, sort that new array, still maintaining key association.  Then throw both your newly sorted array and the original array into array_multisort() and your original array will be sorted to have keys in the same order as your sorted array.

Clear as mud?  The examples on that doc page should help.

Answer (score -1):

How about [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)?

That means looping through each date, check if the previous is bigger, etc.